# cocos2d-x fps isshue on android devices

Tags: android, ios, performance, opengl-es, cocos2d-x

In my game i have scrollable layer, backgrounds and objects are moving from top to bottom with different speed and acceleration.
I have written game on cocos2d-x, everything works fine on apple’s productions. The game is very smooth even on iPod touch 4-th generation.

But i have a problem with android, I have tested:

- Galaxy Frame GT-S6812,
- Nexsus e960,
- Samsung 1997 Infuse 4G,
- Samsung Galaxy S III CDMA,
- Nextbook 8
- LG Nexus 4 E960
- LG Nexsus 5
- Amazon kindle Fire HDX 8.9
- LG optimus Logic L35G LG35G N
- Samsung Galaxy Y Duos S6102

But some other android devices have run without lag. for example:

- Assus Google Nexus 7 1 Gen
- Assus Google Nexus 7 2 Gen
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 P5210 (10 inch)

** Problem: **

When game is running sometimes fps drops down from 60 to 30 or 40 and made annoying lag. My game has 320/480 design resolution and i use hd recourses for these devices. I have been googling about a week but have no results. I tried to build on cocos2d-x 2.2.3 and and 3.2 but there is no difference.**

I can upload apk file of demo version of my Game. (cocos2d-x version of 3.2).

if you have experienced such problem or are interested to solve it we can work together with a good refund, I can share demo source code.

[APK Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/etiei3r8soy9b7f/TestGame.apk?dl=0)

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Stackoverflow users will generally not debug or profile an app for you. You have to narrow down the problem to a specific set of code that you suspect may cause the problem, and is narrowed down enough so it can be posted within the question.

Comment: Ok, I have removed source code...

Comment: What's the format of your images? How many sprites are drawed per frame? How many opengl calls are there per frame? Is there any code which cosumes a lot of cpu?

Comment: I have the same problem on Galaxy S4 even when I have nothing but statistics on the screen. It jitters from 30 to 60 range. This is a good question!